# Telnet port 80 works but http browsing does not ... two different networks? What could this be?

Tags: http, nginx, telnet

I have a trivial Nginx site (just index.html) running on a GCP VM host.

I can telnet to port 80 but browsing this same address gives *connection refused* on three different networks.

I can't imagine *what* is going on ... help please?

Comment: what do you mean networks? Are you telnetting from the same machine as you are browsing?

Comment: Silly questions, but are you sure you're using http (not https) to browse? Are you sure it's actually a web server responding on 80?

Comment: Networks: I tried from my main home network, my phone wifi hotspot, and the local library

Comment: Yes, I'm sure I'm using http. And yes, I'm quite familiar with nginx and I telnetted into port 80 on that machine and put in 'GET /' request and got the expected result